# Как вивести описание сайта на Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Всем привет, пробую написать свой шаблон на Joomla но вот столкнулся с проблемой, как вывести описание самого сайта.

Имя сайта я вывожу так `<?php echo $app->getCfg('sitename');?>` А как вывести само описание?

***PS: Играюсь с Joomla 3.5***

Answer (score 1):

Не пробовали обратиться к документации? Например сюда https://docs.joomla.org/JApplication/getCfg ?

Comment: спасибо, гляну.